# Is there a way to use 13pt as the main document font size with the memoir document class?

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I have been using LaTeX, and I have just checked that the `memoir` class doesn't allow me to uso the Garamondx 13pt ... just 9,10,11,12 and 14pt.

I have printed my book "prototype" and 14 seems a little too big.

Is there a way to set a 13pt font size?

Answer (score 11):

According to the user guide of the `memoir` package, the following default font sizes (in points) are provided: 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 30, 36, 48, and 60. For each of these sizes, a file called `mem?.clo` ìs provided, where `?` can be 9, 10, 11, etc and `clo` stands for "class option". One needs to set the document class option `extrafontsizes` for font sizes that exceed 25pt.

For new font sizes, e.g., `13pt`, you'll have to set up a file named `mem13.clo` along the lines explained in the user guide. For the case of `13pt`, I'd like to suggest you use `mem12.clo` and `mem14.clo` as "templates" and, specifically, average the values used in those two files for the new file.

---

*Addendum*: Here's my attempt to create `mem13.clo` as a convex combination of the parameter settings used in `mem12.clo` and `mem14.clo`. Save it either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second option, do also perform a refresh of the filename database of your TeX distribution.

```
%% This is file `mem13.clo', generated as a convex 
%% combination of mem12.clo and mem14.clo
%%
%%   This work may be distributed and/or modified under
%%   the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, 
%%   either version 1.3 of this license or (at your 
%%   option) any later version.
%%   The latest version of the license is in
%%      http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%   and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions
%%   of LaTeX version 2003/06/01 or later.
%%
%%   This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%%
\ProvidesFile{mem13.clo}%
       [2016/05/17 v0.01 memoir class 13pt size option]
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{13.2}{16.0}%
   \abovedisplayskip 13.2\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7.5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.75\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\newcommand{\small}{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xiipt{14.0}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 10\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus5.5\p@
               \parsep 5.25\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xipt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10.5\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus5.5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.25\p@ \@plus3.25\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 6.25\p@ \@plus2.75\p@ \@minus2.5\p@
               \parsep 3.5\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand*{\miniscule}{\@setfontsize\miniscule\@viiipt{8.8}}
\newcommand*{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@ixpt{10}}
\newcommand*{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@xpt\@xipt}
\newcommand*{\large}{\@setfontsize\large{14.5}{20}}
\newcommand*{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large{18.5}{23.5}}
\newcommand*{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE{22}{27}}
\newcommand*{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge{27}{33}}
\ifextrafontsizes
  \newcommand*{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge{33}{40}}
  \newcommand*{\HUGE}{\@setfontsize\HUGE{40}{48}}
\else
  \let\Huge=\huge
  \let\HUGE=\huge
\fi
\setlength{\onelineskip}{16\p@}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\parindent{1em}
\else
  \setlength\parindent{1.5em}
\fi
\setlength\smallskipamount{3\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}
\setlength\medskipamount{6\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\bigskipamount{12\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\headheight{16\p@}
\setlength\headsep{.3in}
\setlength\topskip{13.2\p@}
\setlength\footskip{33\p@}
\setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}
\setlength\@maxdepth\maxdepth
\setlength\footnotesep{9\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{11.9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\floatsep    {13.2\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\intextsep   {14\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {14\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@fpsep{10\p@ \@plus 2fil}
\setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfpsep{10\p@ \@plus 2fil}
\setlength\@dblfpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\lxvchars{372\p@} % standard 390pt
\setlength\xlvchars{264\p@} %
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\marginparsep{10\p@}
\else
  \setlength\marginparsep{7\p@}
\fi
\setlength{\marginparpush}{7\p@}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mem13.clo'.
```

And here's an MWE that makes use of this new class option file. (Incidentally, I think the sizing command should be named `\minuscule` rather than `\miniscule`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[13pt]{memoir}
\newcommand\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\newcommand\qbfshort{The quick brown fox jumps over\dots}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\miniscule\qbf
\tiny\qbf
\scriptsize\qbf
\footnotesize\qbf
\normalsize\qbf
\large\qbf
\Large\qbf
\LARGE\qbf
\huge\qbf
\Huge\qbfshort
\HUGE\qbfshort
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am relatively new to LaTeX...I regret to say I have never done this before....Where can I find this files for using as templates?

Comment: @Adriano at least on Linux you can put the .clo file in your   `~/texmf` (equivalent to `/home/<username>/texmf`) directory and do a `texhash ~/texmf` `<Enter>` at the command prompt.  This is a wonderful answer, and I know a lot of work went into it.

Comment: @Adriano - You could use the `kpsewhich` utility from a command line to locate any file of the TeX distribution. E.g., `kpsewhich mem12.clo` will return the fully qualified path name of `mem12.clo`.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and TexStudio, is it possible to do this you just showed me @Mico?
I regret to tell you that I have to study more about LaTeX to be able to do that alone.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @Adriano - TeXStudio is a "front end" (aka smart editor) to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution (TeXLive?, MiKTeX?, something else?) do you use? As long as you save the file `mem13.clo` to the directory which contains your main tex file, you should be in business.

Comment: I am using MikTeX.

Comment: @Adriano - Well, just create a new text file in TeXStudio, copy and paste the material for mem13.clo into the new file, and save the file as `mem13.clo`.

Comment: Done. I have created a new document with the information you provided and named it `mem13` with the extension `clo`. Saved it in the same folder I have the `Main.tex` file.

However, it does not seem to recognize the command `13pt`after the `\documentclass[]` due to the resulting fontsize being 12pt.

[http://i.imgur.com/1P3bT7K.jpg]

Comment: @Adriano - Please clarify: Did you try `\documentclass[13pt]{memoir}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40045/discussion-between-adriano-and-mico).

Comment: @Adriano - Sorry, I have a full-time day job. Can't "chat" until this evening.

Comment: About TeX editor, what do you recommend? @Mico

Comment: @Adriano - Not knowing your computing environment, I can't comment knowledgeably. Have you seen the [LaTeX editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5001) posting?

Comment: I Have found it!
`C:\Users\Adriano\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\memoir`
That is where the packages hide themselves.

I have managed to put this edited file there, and made some comparisons...
[http://i.imgur.com/IIqlXln.png]

The author really enjoyed the outcome of the `\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}` package....However, I am the programmer and understand the consequences...so, is it possible to make the `mem13.clo`same font sizes as the package  mentioned above? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched about it...
This package do the trick.

```
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
```

Comment: Is it safe to do this with Memoir?

Comment: Should I erase this answer? @campa

Comment: Well, this answer is a really bad idea. Even if it seems superficially to work right now, the chances that it will cause trouble are extremely high. Moreover, the kinds of problems caused may well be deeply mysterious and difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Do not use any koma package with memoir.  Adriano, use the solution that Mico provided to you.

Comment: I will leave this one here, it may be useful for the ones who have the same idea to know that it is not recommended.

Comment: I found this helpful! Am I part of the problem?