# Memoir font size 13pt

Tags: memoir

This is the original issue: [Is there a way to use 13pt as the main document font size with the memoir document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310055/is-there-a-way-to-use-13pt-as-the-main-document-font-size-with-the-memoir-docume/310065?noredirect=1#comment757574_310065)

I need a document with the 13pt font size in memoir due to 12pt being too small and 14pt too big...

But there is not a 13pt standard font size in memoir.....my first inexperienced attempt was to include the package `\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}`...

But as some people told me here...this may cause consequences after that are really hard to diagnose and solve. However, the author of the book I am editing liked very much the font size offered by the package mentioned above...

As a second attempt I have created a `mem13.clo` file which is basically a new font size 13pt for memoir ... and it includes an average values of the 12pt and 14pt font sizes...Had put it in the `C:\Users\Adriano\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\memoir`.

This is the code:

```
%% This is file `mem13.clo', generated as a convex 
%% combination of mem12.clo and mem14.clo
%%
%%   This work may be distributed and/or modified under
%%   the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, 
%%   either version 1.3 of this license or (at your 
%%   option) any later version.
%%   The latest version of the license is in
%%      http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%   and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions
%%   of LaTeX version 2003/06/01 or later.
%%
%%   This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%%
\ProvidesFile{mem13.clo}%
       [2016/05/17 v0.01 memoir class 13pt size option]
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{13.2}{16.0}%
   \abovedisplayskip 13.2\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7.5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.75\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\newcommand{\small}{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xiipt{14.0}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 10\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus5.5\p@
               \parsep 5.25\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xipt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10.5\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus5.5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.25\p@ \@plus3.25\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 6.25\p@ \@plus2.75\p@ \@minus2.5\p@
               \parsep 3.5\p@ \@plus2.5\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand*{\miniscule}{\@setfontsize\miniscule\@viiipt{8.8}}
\newcommand*{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@ixpt{10}}
\newcommand*{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@xpt\@xipt}
\newcommand*{\large}{\@setfontsize\large{14.5}{20}}
\newcommand*{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large{18.5}{23.5}}
\newcommand*{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE{22}{27}}
\newcommand*{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge{27}{33}}
\ifextrafontsizes
  \newcommand*{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge{33}{40}}
  \newcommand*{\HUGE}{\@setfontsize\HUGE{40}{48}}
\else
  \let\Huge=\huge
  \let\HUGE=\huge
\fi
\setlength{\onelineskip}{16\p@}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\parindent{1em}
\else
  \setlength\parindent{1.5em}
\fi
\setlength\smallskipamount{3\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}
\setlength\medskipamount{6\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\bigskipamount{12\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\headheight{16\p@}
\setlength\headsep{.3in}
\setlength\topskip{13.2\p@}
\setlength\footskip{33\p@}
\setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}
\setlength\@maxdepth\maxdepth
\setlength\footnotesep{9\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{11.9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\floatsep    {13.2\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\intextsep   {14\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {14\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@fpsep{10\p@ \@plus 2fil}
\setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfpsep{10\p@ \@plus 2fil}
\setlength\@dblfpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\lxvchars{372\p@} % standard 390pt
\setlength\xlvchars{264\p@} %
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\marginparsep{10\p@}
\else
  \setlength\marginparsep{7\p@}
\fi
\setlength{\marginparpush}{7\p@}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mem13.clo'.
```

This was the result...

[image]

As you can see...the supposedly 13pt is smaller than the 12pt...my question is...

Is there a way to set the font sizes for `mem13.clo` as the same font sizes used in the `\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}` package? Because the writer really enjoyed that font size and he is willing to keep it like that.

Comment: Real quick: Did you update the filename database of your MiKTeX distribution? If you did not, then placing `mem13.clo` in `C:\Users\Adriano\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\memoir` will do you no good: MikTeX won't be finding the file, meaning that it will use the default font size, which is `10pt`. You should check the log file: is `mem10.cls` or `mem13.cls` being loaded in the document that sets `13pt` as one of the document class options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a little confusing to do. Remember that class options are not dynamic, so since `13pt` is not hardcoded into the class, `memoir` does not recognize it. Instead we need to use the provided interface (page 3-4 in the memoir manual).

Firstly you need to place your `mem13.clo` in a place where LaTeX can find it. For testing it is easiest to just palce it in the same folder as your `.tex` file. If placed elsewhere, then as Mico says in a comment, you need to update the filename DB.

Secondly, we need to use the `*pt` option to tell `memoir` to use a user defined font size file, the name of which HAS to be declared BEFORE `\documentclass`, as placeing it after `\documentclass` after it will be too late (a macro like `\normalsize` or `\normalfont` might be issued by the class while loading).

This works:

```
\newcommand*{\anyptfilebase}{mem}
\newcommand*{\anyptsize}{13}
\documentclass[a4paper,*pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I have the `mem13.clo` in current dir, and in the log I can find the tell-tell

```
 (./mem13.clo)
```

showing that it was loaded.

Yes the interface it a little clunky, but that is due to the fact that we need the clo to be loaded by the class at the right time. Plus `memoir` does not support `key=value` class options

Comment: Done. The log file loads the 13pt font sizes, I have compared them it is really different from each other. Thanks @daleif

Comment: I hope that this way does not create any problems in the future. What do you think?

Comment: It is the solution that is specified in the manual, and I have no intention to change it.