# Set precise font size in memoir class

Tags: memoir, fontsize, bugs

It seems, that there is a problem with font sizes in memoir class.

In the manual of the memoir class, p. 48, it is written that for example using class option 14 pt we'll get `\normalsize = 14` pt.

However actually, using commands `\normalsize \f@size` the output is `14,4` pt. Using Adobe Acrobat Pro one can also check the font size. For this case it is `14,35` pt.

How to set precise font size in memoir class?

In particular, I need to get the size of the text `14,0` bp **in pdf**, i.e. this size should be observed by Adobe Acrobat Pro or, at least, by command `\f@size`, for `\normalsize` text style. I guess I need to establish in memoir class the value of `\normalsize` about `13,5--13,8` Tex pt.

The output with some highlighted strange values.

[image]

**UPD1**: actually as [alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72690/alephzero) explained in comments, there is a difference between abbreviations of point values and real point values in TeX.

**UPD2**: Explanation given in comments by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif): `\huge`, `\Huge` and `\HUGE` commands print the same value as `\LARGE` without `extrafontsizes` option.

And, of cause, I need a way how to get `14,0` bp **in pdf**, i.e. this size should be observed by Adobe Acrobat Pro or, at least, by command `\f@size`, for `\normalsize` text style.

MWE

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
    \begin{document}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20452/44348
    Class option value versus real size.
    \makeatletter

    8pt VS \verb+\miniscule+ \miniscule \f@size

    9pt VS \verb+\tiny+ \tiny \f@size

    10pt VS \verb+\scriptsize+ \scriptsize \f@size

    11pt VS \verb+\footnotesize+ \footnotesize \f@size

    12pt VS \verb+\small+ \small \f@size

    14pt VS \verb+\normalsize+ \normalsize \f@size

    17pt VS \verb+\large+ \large \f@size

    20pt VS\verb+\Large+ \Large \f@size

    25pt VS \verb+\LARGE+ \LARGE \f@size

    30pt VS \verb+\huge+ \huge \f@size

    36pt VS \verb+\Huge+ \Huge \f@size

    48pt VS \verb+\HUGE+ \HUGE \f@size
    \makeatother
    \end{document}
```

Comment: the table is misleading: you're typesetting the 14 pt in 12pt, since you miss braces around the previous line; nevertheless the fonts are geometrically scaled, and that 0.4pt is really around 0.1mm, is really that important?

Comment: The difference between TeX's "14.4 points" and Adobe's "14.35 points" is because TeX uses traditional printer's point sizes where 72.27 points = 1 inch, but Adobe uses "computer points" where 72 points (exactly) = 1 inch. If you want to match Adobe-sized points in TeX, measure them in "big points" with units `bp` not `pt`.

Comment: @Moriambar, thank you for the comment. Yes, it would be better to write braces. `0.1 mm` is not important for me, however I've tried to follow formal requirements for my paper submission. I guess, nobody will notice the difference.

Comment: it's not a bug just your misunderstanding of the difference between tex and postscript points,  we have several answers explaining the units used by tex.

Comment: @alephzero, thank you so much for the explanation about Adobe's points.

Comment: In TeX (before LaTeX) Knuth made the typographic decision that fonts should be scaled in increments of 20% exactly. That's where the sizes 10, 12, 14.4, 17.28, 20.736, 24.8832, 29.85984, 35.831808 originally came from. Rounding them to 10, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 30, 36 is a mostly about making the *names* easier to use and remember - but one could quibble about whether "20" should really be "21".

Comment: @Moriambar "0.4pt is really around 0.1mm, is really that important?" If you have 40 lines of text per page, those 0.1mm increments change the total height of the text block by 4mm, which *is* important if you care about such things! 4mm is about the same height as an extra line of text on the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you, I'll search information about postscript points. However, perhaps, there is a bug at least in `\huge`, `\Huge` and `\HUGE` values.  The general problem is how to set the arbitrary font size  in PDF using `memoir` class.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko hmm yes cuts off at 25pt which the  manual seems to say explicitly isn't the case, hmmmm

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko see this on bp/pt units https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point/200968#200968

Comment: I have pinged the memoir maintainer in chat to ask that he look at  the font sizes...

Comment: I'll have a look when time permits (not at pc), feel free to send me an email so I don't forget. All information related to 14pt is in mem14.clo

Comment: Had a dig through the dtx. By default in 14pt, huge, Huge and HUGE are equal to LARGE, unless  the extrafontsizes option is used.

Comment: @daleif, many thanks, I'll update the question according to your explanations. So, I'll have only one problem how to set `14 bt` instead of `14 TeX pt`.

Comment: You'll have to roll your own clo file (I think that is the easiest) . There is an option for specifying what that external file is named. Though I do not remember the details. It is in the manual

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of you will need the  `extrafontsizes` class option to activate the very large huge data. It is not well described in the manual. I've added that to my TODO list.

To change the font sizes to something more specific, create your own clo file. Say `myfont14.clo`, then start the document with

```
\providecommand*{\anyptfilebase}{myfont}
\providecommand*{\anyptsize}{14} 
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,*pt]{memoir}
```

Copy the contents of `mem14.clo` to `myfont14.clo` and adjust it accordingly. Note that you can use

```
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{14bp}{17.5bp}%
```

instead of the syntax used in `mem14.clo` which assumes pt.

With `14bp` `\f@size` says 14.05249, which should be the pt equivalent of the bp value.

Comment: thank you for the explanations. I'll try to implement your recommendations on Sunday and perhaps, ask some extra questions (if nobody presents more detailed answer).

Comment: your method works very well. Futhermore, it helps to run for example this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310065/44348.  Why that example does not work without `\providecommand*`? I would be very grateful if you explain the meaning of the following options: `{17.5bp}` from your explanation, `\@xipt`, `\@xviipt` etc and the general logic how to set this values to get a success.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko which example are you referring to? Here providecommand is just useful, it defined the macro if it does not already exist. `\@xipt` is probably the same as `{11pt}` might also be just `{11}` as the macro will use pt if no unit is give (AFAIR). The actual value of 17.5 is the baselineskip, it is an arbitrary value, I think I just too the pt value from mem14 and used that. The `\@xipt`  macros stem from a period of history where computers did not have a lot of memory, to latex `\@xipt` us one token `{11pt}` is at least 4.

Comment: I meant that somehow this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310065/44348 does not work without your hint. Thanks for explanation. I think we should use the baselineskip according to the memoir class options. It seems that `17,5` leads to the larger vertical skip before  `14pt VS \verb+\normalsize+ \normalsize \f@size`, than after this line. I found, that e.g. `\@setfontsize\footnotesize{11bp}{13.6bp}` gives good vertical skips. Do you have an idea how to set `baselineskip` options in MWE?

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko again you need to be more specific. The baselineskip refers to the font size, each time you set a font size and a baselineskip. AFAIR memoir cannot load just any memX.clo for a given x, they are hard-coded into memoir (not sure that is true) thus you need to tell it exactly what to load. This does that.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko what exactly are you saying it not working without what.

Comment: your approach is working excellent!) Good explanations! I've just spent some time to tune `.clo`